# DateTime in jqGrid PostData while RelaodGrid Operation

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Consider the following dummy code in a JavaScript file in an ASP.Net MVC5 Project.

```
var $grid = $("#grid")
var postData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
postData["xyzId"] = $("#xyzId").val();
postData["date"] = $("#date").val();
$grid.setGridParam({ postData: postData });
$grid.setGridParam({ datatype: "json", page: 1 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Following is the Controller's ActionMethod where the request arrives...

```
public ActionResult GetXyz(int xyzId, DateTime? date)
```

Keeping the date nullable is the need because it is an optional selection.

**PROBLEM:** 
The date format in Culture settings of .Net Framework is "DD/MM/YYYY" and when we send "02/10/2016" it accepts as "February 10, 2016" (which is wrong btw) but when we send "16/10/2016" it reads it as null. This is only happening when we are passing dates in jqGrid Reload operation. Whereas, in normal ajax call, everythins is working well
e.g. "02/10/2016" => "October 02, 2016",
and "16/10/2016" => "October 16, 2016".

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you tried to send the date in ISO format "2016-02-10" (February 10, 2016)? Which version of `Newtonsoft.Json` you use?

Comment: @Oleg. I was finding your profile to mention here.Thanks a million for the response. Well, we are passing the value as user selects from the calendar (DD/MM/YYYY), we are not converting it to any other formats. Do we need to convert?

Comment: It's recommended to use only locale independent formats to transfer the data. It's common rule for numbers, date, ... Do you tried to convert `$("#date").val()` to the format `YYYY-MM-DD` before assigning to `postData.xyzId`? I think that ISO date format is default for Newtonsoft.Json used in MVC 5.

Comment: Once again, you rock @Oleg. This seems to be working. I will let you know after testing. Thanks. Thumbs Up!

Comment: @Oleg, can you post it into an answer so I can mark that as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's recommended to use only *locale independent formats* to transfer the data. It's common rule for numbers, date, ... You can convert `$("#date").val()` to the format `YYYY-MM-DD` ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of date) *before* assigning to `postData.xyzId`? I think that ISO date format is default for `Newtonsoft.Json` used in MVC.

Typically one use `formatter: "date"` with optional `formatoptions` with `newformat` property. In the way you hold internally and transfer only locale independent data, but the user will see local specific dates (based on `formatoptions.newformat` which you specify explicitly in `colModel` or the implicit value inherited from `grid.locale-XX.js`).

Comment: I am doing this now. And it works fine.

postData["date"] = Converter.dateTimeStringToUtcDateTime($("#date").val()).toJSON()

Comment: And, in my Converter Module (using Revealing Modular Pattern),

var dateTimeStringToUtcDateTime = function(value, sourceFormat) {
        return moment(value, sourceFormat || Common.dateTimeFormat.shortDatePattern).utc();
    };

Answer (score 2):

Catch the date as string

```
public ActionResult GetXyz(int xyzId, string date="")
```

and then format it in conventional way:

```
var Date= DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Hope this will help  :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I do not want to receive dates as string and then parse that into date. Framework should have some builtin implementation for that.

Comment: I thought you need the solution.

Comment: Yes, and thanks for your time. But, I think Oleg's solution makes more sense to me.